# socket timeout when when connecting to a mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, jenkins

I'm trying to connect to a mongoDB, and getting a MongoTimeoutException. When run locally, everything works as expected, but when run from inside a Jenkins project, the timeout occurs.

```
 private JsonNode getMongoResponse(String mongoURL, String mongoPort, String mongoDB, String mongoCollection, String userId, String userPW, String requestId) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapperResponse = new ObjectMapper();
    String responseStringFull = "[null]";
    MongoClient mongoClient = null;
    JsonNode responseObj = null;
    String responseString = null;
    Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver");
    mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://" + userId + ":" + userPW + "@" + mongoURL + ":" + mongoPort));
    MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDB);
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection(mongoCollection);
    try {
        FindIterable<Document> tempVal = collection.find(eq("extId", requestId)).sort(eq("timestamp", -1));
        responseStringFull = tempVal.first().toJson();
        responseObj = objectMapperResponse.readValue(responseStringFull, JsonNode.class).get("payload");
        responseString = "[" + responseObj.toString() + "]";
        responseObj = objectMapperResponse.readValue(responseString, JsonNode.class);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException stoex) {
        System.out.println("Socket Timeout: " + stoex.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (MongoTimeoutException mtoe) {
        System.out.println("Mongo Timeout: " + mtoe.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(Thread_fetchMongoResults.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, mtoe);
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("i/o exception: " + ioe.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(Thread_fetchMongoResults.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, mtoe);
        return null;
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        return null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(Thread_fetchMongoResults.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
    mongoClient.close();
    return responseObj;
}
```

The following is the error message I'm getting:

```
Mongo Timeout: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=[dbAddress]:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]
at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:377)
at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:104)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:63)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:402)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:510)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:81)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl$FindOperationIterable.first(FindIterableImpl.java:216)
at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:156)
...
```

I'm currently using the mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar library.

Please pardon all of the separate errors; I put them in to try to debug this issue and I've spent the better part of the day trying to find a way to lengthen the mongo connect timeout but I can't seem to find the correct keywords for goggle to come up with something that works.

If anyone could help me, I would be eternally grateful.

ETA: This started occurring after a server migration and the above code works perfectly on non-migrated mongo databases. I'm willing to bet that there is a problem with the way they set things up during the migration but I can still connect to the database with a mongoclient outside of the java code so I know the database is accessible.

Comment: What is the URL you use to connect to Mongo? Doesn't it point to some local or private address (like 192.168.x.x)? Doesn't firewall block access from Jenkins machine to Mongo machine?

Comment: It's an internal corporate DNS name that I'm connecting to. I got the IP via dslookup and tried that with the same result unfortunately. It might be a firewall issue but the jenkins server is behind out firewall so that *shouldn't* be an issue.

Comment: Correction to my previous reply: the mongoDB was migrated to an AWS server, so I'm going to see if a firewall exception does need to be added. Thanks for hopefully pointing me in the proper direction. I'll update if this is what is causing the problem.